# Should I use static methods, Instance methods or Common Methods Class?

Tags: java, android, performance

How should I decide which methods to use? Static, instance or Common instance?

For now, I'm keeping instance methods separate in class.

```
private boolean storeValuesAndValidateFields() {
    clearStrings(mName, mEmail, mPhone, mRegistrationKey, mPassword);

    mName = nameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    mEmail = emailEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    mPhone = phoneEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    mRegistrationKey = registrationKeyEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    mPassword = passwordEditText.getText().toString().trim();

    return (!nameEditText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() || !emailEditText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()
    || !phoneEditText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty() || !registrationKeyEditText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty()
    || !passwordEditText.getText().toString().trim().isEmpty());

}
```

How can I decide the most efficient way & what is the most efficient way in case of above code?

Comment: where is it ? clearStrings(mName, mEmail, mPhone, mRegistrationKey, mPassword);

Comment: It's different methods defined in same class.

Comment: try to use databinding

Comment: then you don't need to repeat get and set value again and again

Comment: Thank you bugfreerammohan! Can you give some links to refer?

Comment: Why are you calling `toString()` on objects that are already `Strings`? And why do you keep doing it over and over again? Calling methods pointlessly has as much impact on performance as the difference between static and non-static methods. You would be better off analysing your own code for redundancies.

Answer (score 0):

Well you have a lot of duplicate code there since you are already calling `getText().toString().trim()` on all of the objects and assigning that to a field, you could just use that field for boolean expression you are returning, like this:

```
private boolean storeValuesAndValidateFields() {
    clearStrings(mName, mEmail, mPhone, mRegistrationKey, mPassword);

    mName = nameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    mEmail = emailEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    mPhone = phoneEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    mRegistrationKey = registrationKeyEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    mPassword = passwordEditText.getText().toString().trim();

    return (!mName.isEmpty() || !mEmail.isEmpty() || !mPhone.isEmpty() || !mRegistrationKey.isEmpty()
    || !mPassword.isEmpty());
}
```

This will make code a lot more readable, and it removes duplicate method calls.

Comment: Thank Dusko for making the code better. But I'm asking for overall solution. For example, Should I make this method static so that I can use it everywhere in my app?

Comment: @cooldev You can't make it static just like that. It relies on a large number of instance member fields as inputs, which you would have to convert to parameters. What exactly would be the point?

Comment: My code did make it more efficient since I removed duplicate method calls thus speeding it up. It is extremely small improvement, but it is improvement nonetheless.